# Bad array initialization vs assignment copy constructor initialization

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    Test(){}
    Test(int param):i(param){}
    int i;
};

int main()
{

    Test obj1(100);
    //Test obj2[100](obj1) ;  - This doesn't work I know
    Test obj3[10] = obj1; //This works
    cout<<obj3[9].i<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

In the above code `Test obj2[100](obj1);` doesn't work but `Test obj3[10] = obj1;`

Why is the former supported but latter.(Both would be calling the copy constructor.)

Is that the former isn't supported because of implementation constrains in compilers?

Edit: I am not using c++11.
gcc version 4.8.2 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev3, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
Qt 5.3.1

Any conclusion?

Comment: It doesn't work because it's not allowed. `()` is value-initialization unless it's an array, then the program is ill-formed.

Comment: @Puppy don't mince words; tell us how you *really* feel about native arrays =P

Comment: `Test obj3[10] = obj1; //This works` - really? clang 3.5 pukes all over this regardless of mode (c++11 or otherwise).

Comment: @WhozCraig GCC bug or extension then.

Comment: You need to say what compiler and settings you are using.

Comment: @remyabel apparently, or whatever other mysterious compiler the OP is using.

Comment: The mysterious compiler would be GCC with any version from 4.5 to 4.9 (just tested that snippet over at godbolt.org). But don't ask me what it's actually supposed to mean to the compiler, presumably it value-initializes the first element of the array?

Comment: @Damon clang gives a nice error: "error: array initializer must be an initializer list"

Comment: @juanchopanza: Well yes, it's definitely clear what the error is, and what the code _should_ look like. What I'm not getting is what GCC (which compiles without error or warning) makes of it. My best guess is that it silently adds curly braces. However, there seems to be no mention of such an extension in the docs (none that I could find anyway).

Comment: @Damon It certainy has strange behaviour. On my platform, it seems to initialize all elements to the same value. That is not equivalent to adding curly braces. I am compiling with `-std=c++11` and `-pedantic-errors` so in principle it shouldn't allow extensions.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I wonder if GCC is maybe correct, following some very liberal language lawyering. 8.5.1/11 gives conditions under which braces can be elided in a declaration of the form `T x = {a};`, which is basically there being a sub-aggregate. In the example, the array is an aggregate, and `Test` (being a class) is its sub-aggregate. So... twisting the wording to the extreme, this would be legal...

Comment: @Damon `Test` is not an aggregate because it has user defined constructors. But brace elision is one of those things on which compilers tend to disagree.

Comment: What am I supposed to do further with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm mainly answering your last comment, because all elements were already given in comments.

What can we see :

- first syntax `Test obj2[100](obj1);` is rejected as error by all compilers tested because ... it does not follows specification for C++ language !
- second syntax `Test obj2[100] = obj1;` does not seem to cleanly fit to current specifications because you initialize an array with a single element. More on that :

  - clang (and MSVC) will clash on it : they require curly braces and then initialize only first element (would be : `Test obj2[100] = {obj1};`)
  - gcc (4.5 to 4.9) accepts it and initializes all elements of array with a copy of `obj1`

My opinion is that as it unclear that it is correct C++ and as it causes errors on some heavily used C++ compilers, you should avoid to use even the second syntax, unless documenting that in red flashing font.